# Loop Audio Specified Amount of Times Html5 or Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, loops, audio

I need to look this typing sound over and over again until my typing animation is done. I know I can use an audio editor to extend the sound but I just want to know if there is any way to do this with just html5 and javascript. I need to loop it a specific number of times then stop it.

Here is my code:

```
<audio autoplay>
<source src="sfx_typing.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
<embed height="50" width="100" src="sfx_typing.mp3">
</audio>
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

This also should happen on page load with no delay and no plugins should be used in the audio playing.

Comment: <audio data-hops=5 onended="if(this.dataset.hops--) this.play()" autoplay >

Comment: Thanks dandavis, if you post it, I'll make it answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `play()` audio again in `ended` event handler.